# Inherit 1 method from other class

Tags: php, inheritance

I'm making a little CMS / webshop. I'm following the MVC pattern.

I'm stuck at a problem with I have faced before but I think solved wrong.

So here it is:
I have two classes called "User" and "Message".
The class "User" has a method "getUsers" which return all users in an array.

Now I also need to get all the users in the "Message" class. Before I just duplicated the method into the "Message" class. But I will need this "getUsers" function in more classes.

I was thinking about inherit the class but then I inherit all the items and I only want that method. Maybe I could make a god class that has all these special functions I need and then inherit my classes from that god class. But that seems a bit stupid since I will have a unordered class with every bits and pieces.

So how do I correctly solve this issue with PHP 5.3?

Thanks for the help, I hope you can solve the problem

Comment: what do you mean by get all the users in the message class?  It sounds like a message user system?

Comment: I need to get all the user names to send a message to a user. Doesn't really matter which class it is. The problem is the same for other classes

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you describe it would seem like the `getUsers()` method is actually not related to each class in particular but to all classes that need to get all users. If this is the case then a [`static`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) method in the `User` class seems like a good choice.

```
class User {
    public static function getUsers() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then everytime you need all users you can get the them by calling `User::getUsers();`.

---

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the comments this is not a good approach since it introduces a high dependecy upon the `User` class. See [Static Methods are Death to Testability](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/) and [`static` considered harmful](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html).

Comment: This will tightly couple all classes needing that method to the User class, hampering reuse and changeability of the code. It will also make testing pure pain because you cannot mock the User class. There is no reason to use a static method here. See http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability and http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html

Answer (score 1):

So your `Message` class depends on your `User` class. The best way to solve it would be to use Dependency Injection:

```
$user = new User();
$message = new Message($user);

class Message 
{
    protected $_user;

    public function __construct(User $user) 
    {
        $this->_user = $user;
    }

    public function methodThatNeedsUser() 
    {
        $userList = $this->_user->getUsers();
        ...
    }

}
```

Or as an alternative with no coupling, just pass the array of users

```
$user = new User();
$message = new Message();
$message->methodThatNeedsUser($user->getUsers());

class Message 
{
    public function methodThatNeedsUser(array $userList) 
    {
        // do something with $userList
    }

}
```

I think you get the point.

Answer (score 1):

You could just create an instance of the Users class in your Message class and call the getUsers method afterwards. 
Perhaps a better approach would be to pass that instance as parameter to either the constructor or to a method of the Message class. Or you could pass that User array as an argument. I don't know how your classes are designed, but it should work that way. 
I recommend to extract an interface from the existing Users class and code against that to avoid tight coupling of your classes

Answer (score 0):

I would propose create a simple collection class based on ArrayObject.

```
class UserCollection extends ArrayObject() {

    public function load($criterion) {
        //loop with $this->append($user);
    }
}

$users = new UserCollection();
$users->load($criterion);
```

Comment: If it can load, presumably from a datasource, it's more like a Repository than mere collection. Also, when it contains objects, consider SplObjectStorage over ArrayObject.

Comment: Good idea about SplObjectStorage but we haven't got much info about class structure in this project.:) So I think maybe he can use simple array for user now.

Comment: True. But my main point was that your Collection looks like a Repository anyway ;) And I am not sure it answers the OP's question on how to make that available in the "other" classes.

Comment: This is an approach how to avoid create a static method for getting collection of users or use entity user for returning ones. You could create a collection(repository is more common name but i'd prefer to use name Collection for classes) and create it inside the message class or in other classes. Imho, it's necessary to change original scheme of classes.

Comment: @AndrejL I don't think creating the Repository class directly inside the Message class is the right way. That creates a high dependency. I think what you're trying to solve is the tight coupling between model and data source?